# Get daily averages from sar

Tags: ubuntu, sar

Is there a way to just display a given days averages using sar. I currently do something like the following:

```
sar -u -s 00:00:00 -e 23:59:59 -f /var/log/sysstat/sa10
```

And just take the last (average) line to add to a report. But it would be nice and easy to just gen my report if I could pass an argument to just spit-out the average. I could not find such an option in the sar documentation. So, unless I am missing it, I am guessing the option is no. However, It's very possible I'm missing it or there might be another tool other than sar that might expose this functionality.

Comment: Is this is what you are looking for?
`sar -u -s 00:00:00 -e 23:59:59 -f /var/log/sysstat/sa10 | tail -1`

Comment: @Ramesh - write that up as an A. That's the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the average by piping the tail command to your command. By this way, your command will always return only one line.

```
sar -u -s 00:00:00 -e 23:59:59 -f /var/log/sysstat/sa10 | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using sar...but there are accounting utilities in that package that will help you on a given days' worth of SAR output.  This is usually installed as a crontab entry (commented out) running as adm or sys sometimes as root.  In later linux versions, it is installed as /etc/cron.d/sysstat.   Look at the sa1 and sa2 commands.  They are /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 and sa2 and work as a team.  sa1 stores data in binary form when called and sa2 takes the binary file from sa1 and generates a textual report containing the averages.

There is ample information on this scheme, just do an appropriate google search like 'linux sa utilities'.

Answer (score 0):

Using tail requires you to know how many lines you anticipate of average statistics. If you want average stats for each cpu and you have used -P ALL then the tail command is cumbersome.

I suggest simply grep'ing for `Average`. To get the header, which is a comment inserted by sadc, you need to add the -C option:

```
# sar -P ALL -C | grep Average:
Average:        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
Average:        all      3.06      0.00      1.22      0.00      0.00     95.72
Average:          0      0.55      0.00      0.23      0.01      0.00     99.21
Average:          1      1.96      0.00      0.77      0.00      0.00     97.26
Average:          2      3.84      0.00      1.63      0.00      0.00     94.52
Average:          3      0.59      0.00      0.24      0.00      0.00     99.17
Average:          4      0.51      0.00      0.27      0.01      0.00     99.21
Average:          5      1.78      0.00      0.74      0.01      0.00     97.47
Average:          6      8.02      0.00      3.16      0.01      0.00     88.81
Average:          7      6.75      0.00      2.61      0.00      0.00     90.64
Average:          8     10.93      0.00      4.20      0.01      0.00     84.86
Average:          9      6.47      0.00      2.54      0.01      0.00     90.98
Average:         10      9.76      0.00      3.72      0.02      0.00     86.50
Average:         11      5.42      0.00      2.03      0.01      0.00     92.54
Average:         12      0.07      0.00      0.05      0.00      0.00     99.89
Average:         13      0.31      0.00      0.18      0.00      0.00     99.51
Average:         14      0.02      0.00      0.21      0.00      0.00     99.78
Average:         15      0.06      0.00      0.08      0.00      0.00     99.86
Average:         16      0.14      0.00      0.07      0.00      0.00     99.79
Average:         17      0.03      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     99.93
Average:         18      8.03      0.00      3.16      0.00      0.00     88.80
Average:         19      1.41      0.00      0.56      0.00      0.00     98.02
Average:         20      2.62      0.00      1.06      0.00      0.00     96.32
Average:         21      0.37      0.00      0.16      0.00      0.00     99.47
Average:         22      0.07      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     99.89
Average:         23      3.66      0.00      1.43      0.00      0.00     94.90
```